# script en servidor linux ubuntu, número de procesos huérfanos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, unix, ubuntu-server

Hola espero me puedan ayudar con este ejercicio, de antemano gracias.

Crear una script que enumera en la pantalla del usuario el número de procesos huérfanos para cada cuenta UNIX recibida desde la línea de comandos.

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
$ Script_02 al911911 a1234567 A2024507 luisflo ltrejo LFlores
La cuenta UNIX al911911 de "Santiago Nasar" tiene 7 procesos huérfanos.
La cuenta UNIX a1234567 de "Luis Pasos" tiene 1 procesos huérfanos.
La cuenta UNIX A2024507 de "Israel Buendia" tiene 4 procesos huérfanos.
La cuenta de UNIX luisflo de "Luis Flores" tiene 5 procesos huérfanos.
Error: La cuenta de UNIX “ltrejo” no está registrada en el sistema.
Error: La cuenta de UNIX “LFlores” no está registrada en el sistema.
```

Posdata ya pude resolverlo

```
if [ $# -ne 0 ]
then
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
    Valor=`egrep $1 /etc/passwd`

    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
      echo -e "\n Error: la cuenta UNIX \"$1\" no esta registrada en el sistema. \a"
    else
      Cons=1
      HNet=`ps -lu $1 | awk '{print $4 " " $5}' | egrep " 1" | wc -l`
      HPro=`expr $HNet - $Cons`
      Name=`egrep $1 /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f5`

      if [ $HNet -eq 0 ]
      then
        echo -e "\n La cuenta UNIX $1 de \"$Name\" tiene $HNet procesos huerfanos. "
      else
        echo -e "\n La cuenta UNIX $1 de \"$Name\" tiene $HPro procesos huerfanos. "
      fi
    fi
    shift 1
  done
else
  echo -e "\n Error: el script necesita al menos un argumento. \a"
fi
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO! Alguna pregunta?

Comment: Que ha intentado?

Comment: tengo este pipeline que hace lo del ejercicio pero lo necesito como script 
>
ps -lu "cuenta" | cut -c 21-21 | egrep 1 | wc -l

Comment: Por favor, pon la solución como respuesta, abajo en el campo Tu Respuesta. En un rato incluso puedes marcarla como aceptada para que otros puedan saber que hay solución a la pregunta :)